# Consulta en MySQL uniendo varias tablas

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta en mysql en varias tablas a la vez pero los resultados que me saca no me terminan de servir.

Este es el código que estoy usando:

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM `Articulos` art 
INNER JOIN `Direcciones&Codigos` ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC;
```

A ver si soy capaz de explicarme de que necesito exactamente.
Son 3 tablas distintas. 
Artículos:  Donde guardo los datos del articulo.
Direcciones&codigos: Donde guardo códigos Ean, las tallas y colores y la referencia.
Configuraciones: Donde guardo los nombres de las cosas tipo Materiales, sexo, tallas, etc.

Ahora mismo tal cual esta montada la consulta me saca como resultados una mezcla de Artículos y Códigos. Como cada articulo puede tener 3000 códigos pues me saca de cada articulo 3000 resultados.

El caso es que yo solo quiero que me saque el resultado del articulo en cuestión, pero claro tengo que buscar en direcciones&codigos por si lo que estoy buscando es la referencia o el código ean ( que en ese caso si me saca solo un resultado ). 
Por ejemplo, si $buski = cinturones que me saque todos los resultados que como nombre tenga cinturones, no que me saque todos los que se llamen cinturones y todas sus posibles códigos.

He probado también a filtrar los resultados con un `array_values(array_unique($DAutoCom));` pero entonces solo me saca un único resultado.

¿Que puedo hacer para que el array solo muestre los resultados de la tabla Artículos?

Digamos que solo tengo que eliminar todos los que en la tabla artículos tengan el id duplicado y que solo muestre uno de ellos.

el bucle lo construyo con esto:

```
$R_auto_Articulos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $C_auto_Articulos);
if ($R_auto_Articulos && mysqli_num_rows($R_auto_Articulos)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($R_auto_Articulos, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

que lo mismo para que muestre solo 1 resultado por id se hace ahi.

Comment: El problema no es filtrar el array sino crear una consulta que te de exactamente los datos que quieras, no datos para luego desechar una parte. Eso sería como cargar un camión con productos nuevos de los cuales una parte los echas a la basura cuando el camión llega a su destino. Si explicas con un poco más de claridad lo que quieres alguien te echará una mano con tu consulta pero facilítale el trabajo.

Comment: Entiendo el porque de tus "like" y "or", pero no entiendo por qué el "and 'borrado' = 0". Por lo que veo 'borrado' es una columna de alguna de esas 3 tablas que describes, pero, está bien hecho el "where"!?! es decir donde están los paréntesis?.

Comment: @Rostan el AND borrado = 0 es porque borrado si o si y sea la anterior condición la que sea esa tiene que ser 0

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa para que te muestre solamente los datos del artículo, pero que te permita filtrar por ean es realizar una sub consulta y aplicar el filtro ahí.

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo
-- ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM `Articulos` art 
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%')  AND `borrado` = 0 
AND art.id in (
    select ean.idcosa 
    from `Direcciones&Codigos` ean 
    where  ean.`3` LIKE '%".$buski."%' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%')
)
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC;
```

Aplicando esto no se podrá mostrar la siguiente columna:

```
-- ean.id AS IdEan
```

Comment: El -- es importante? ¿exactamente que hace eso?... De momento he probado el código pero no muestra ningún resultado, estoy mirando si soy capaz de entenderlo para ver porque ahora no muestra nada.

Comment: El -- solo comenta la linea, ya que si aplicas la sub consulta no se va a poder mostrar esa columna

Comment: Te recomendaría que pruebes la sub consulta primero, para ver si devuelve datos. Ahora corregí el ejemplo, tenía error de sintaxis.

Comment: En eso estoy  probando las consultas separadas a ver porque no me devuelve nada

Comment: Analizando de vuelta la consulta, decidí modificar algo para que te permita filtrar mejor, ¿podrías fijarte en el ejemplo?

Comment: Y el AND art.id in(... no seria un OR?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60545/discussion-between-blasito-and-killpe).

Answer (score 1):

Primero, ¿me puedes mostrar como relacionas las tablas?,
¿Qué quieres hacer luego de obtener la consulta desde las 3 tablas?,
¿Quieres sumar un articulo en cuestion?.

Yo soy mas partidario de meterlo en una lista y sumar con linq ej: listado.sum(e <= e.objetoasumar).Tolist(); al principio cuesta pero es mucho mas amigable y así haces tu negocio por el codebehind y no por sql.

---

Prueba esto:

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM Articulos art 
INNER JOIN Direcciones&Codigos ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
LEFT JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.id = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC;
```

Comment: En principio las relacionó en la misma consulta.  El id de la tabla artículos es el mismo que el idcosa de la tabla direcciones&codigos

Comment: Entiendo que con el Left join te estas trayendo los datos de la tabla de direcciones&codigos, pero esa tabla no tiene datos de sexo que es lo que recupero de Configuraciones, de todos modos la idea es que solo me muestre un resultado único por cada id de Artículos

Answer (score 1):

prueba esto

```
   SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM Articulos art 
INNER JOIN Direcciones&Codigos ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
LEFT JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.id = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC;
```

Comment: Es igual que la de arriba ¿no?