# Obtener resultados de dos campos en subconsulta mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy tratando de recuperar dos campos de una subconsulta pero no doy con la tecla para que me los muestre.

este es el código que tengo:

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo
FROM `Articulos` art
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%')  AND `borrado` = 0 
OR art.id in (
    SELECT ean.idcosa
    FROM `Direcciones&Codigos` ean 
    WHERE ean.`3` LIKE '%".$buski."%' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%')
)
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC;
```

los datos que necesito sacar son en la subconsulta de Direcciones&codigo y los campos se llaman 1 y 2.

el array lo saco así:

```
$R_auto_Articulos = mysqli_query($Conectar, $C_auto_Articulos);
if ($R_auto_Articulos && mysqli_num_rows($R_auto_Articulos)) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($R_auto_Articulos, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
```

He probado a crear un alias en la subconsulta con esto: ean.2 AS Eanta y luego recuperarlo con $row["Eanta"] pero en el momento que meto el alias deja de devolver resultados la consulta :(

¿Hay alguna forma de sacar el valor que tienen los campos 1 y 2 de alguna forma?

La estructura de la tabla artículos es:

```
id: int
nombre: varchar
sexo: int
precio: varchar
temporada: int
borrado: int
```

La estructura de las tablas de Direcciones&codigos es:

```
id: int
incosa: int (id de articulo)
1: int (talla)
2: int (color)
3: int (código ean)
4: int (código de uso interno)
```

la union de las dos tablas se hace haciendo coincidir el id de artículos con incosa de la tabla direcciones&codigos.

Realmente con la subconsulta si busco el código ean aparece, si busco el nombre del articulo aparece, si busco el código de uso interno aparece... con lo cual me va genial a falta de poder recuperar de esa tabla la talla y el color.

Antes tenia una consulta con un inner a esa tabla pero me mostraba resultados duplicados de la tabla Artículos ya que cada código ean se asigna a un producto cartesiano creado a partir de el nombre del articulo + talla + color. con lo que en la tabla direcciones y códigos hay de un mismo articulo como 20 referencias. Como me el array me tiraba el listado de las 20 referencias opté por hacer la subconsulta.

El código que tenia antes es este:

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM `Articulos` art 
INNER JOIN `Direcciones&Codigos` ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC
```

En la tabla direcciones&codigos guardo las tallas y colores de cada articulo con lo cual se ve que con esa consulta trata cada id de direcciones&codigos como un registro mas de Artículos y realmente quiero que en el array solo me salga el resultado de los registros que hay en artículos.

No se si habrá alguna forma de filtrar con este código que solo muestre un resultado por id de la tabla artículos, si así fuera también me valdría como solución.

Muchísimas gracias a todos por vuestra ayuda...

Comment: Te digo [lo mismo que te comenté en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/78959/29967), la cual no sé si dejaste abandonada abriendo una nueva pregunta. Es necesario que te detengas a analizar cómo están diseñadas las tablas de la base de datos y como dependen las tablas unas de otras, pues no deberías tener duplicados en un buen diseño. Un código no tiene por qué funcionar a la fuerza, a veces, lo que hay que hacer es replantearse las cosas desde el principio.

Comment: La única unión que tienen es el id de artículos con idcosa de direcciones&codigos que son el mismo campo para poder relacionar ambas tablas. @A.Cedano

Comment: Comparte las estructuras y datos para poderte ayudar. Ya que en la  pregunta anterior, que es sobre lo mismo, no compartiste la información. Saludos.

Comment: es que no se exportar la estructura @Rostan

Comment: a ver si así esta mejor explicado @Rostan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con tu explicación veo un poco mas claro tu problema y me parece que tu solución este en tu mismo código, solo que omites agregar un **GROUP BY** al final. para que no te genere DUPLICIDAD, y escoger la columnas necesarias en el **SELECT**.

```
SELECT 
    art.id AS IdArt,
    art.nombre AS NombrArt,
    conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
    ean.`1` AS 1Ean,
    ean.`2` AS 2Ean
FROM `Articulos` art 
INNER JOIN `Direcciones&Codigos` ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR 
    ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR 
    ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND 
    `borrado` = 0 
GROUP BY art.id, 
    art.nombre,
    conf.Conf1,
    ean.`1`,
    ean.`2`
ORDER BY art.id
```

Espero con ello de a tu solución, saludos.

Comment: Perfectooooooooo, le he tenido que hacer unos pequeños cambios que al poner tanta cosa en group salia lo mismo que sin el, pero dejándole solo art.id funciona perfecto. Mil graciaaaas :)

Comment: No te preocupes, un gusto haberte ayudado y no olvides cerrar la pregunta anterior, suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres es mostrar el contenido de la tabla **Articulos** y sólo los resultados coincidentes de la tabla **Direcciones&Codigos** utiliza la instrucción **LEFT OUTER JOIN**, de lo contrario puedes utilizar **RIGHT OUTER JOIN**, modifico tu consulta para ser más claro.

```
SELECT 
*,
art.id AS IdArt,
art.nombre AS NombrArt,
conf.Conf1 AS Sexo,
ean.id AS IdEan 
FROM `Articulos` art 
**LEFT OUTER** JOIN `Direcciones&Codigos` ean ON art.id = ean.idcosa 
INNER JOIN `Configuraciones` conf ON art.sexo = conf.Conf_id 
WHERE UPPER(CONCAT(art.nombre,art.temporada)) LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') OR ean.`3` = '".$buski."' OR ean.`4` LIKE UPPER('%".$buski."%') AND `borrado` = 0 
ORDER BY art.temporada DESC, art.material DESC
```

Comment: Me siguen saliendo todos los resultados cruzados de direcciones&codigos :(